# Archivos JSON entrelazados por una url

Tags: javascript, json

Buen día.

Tengo 1 archivo json que contiene un campo url que a su vez lleva a otro archivo json.

Cómo puedo hacer para que cuando el usuario visualice el primer json en una página web y le de clic a ese enlace, aparezca el otro archivo json.

La idea es no crear diferentes páginas web que llamen a json, sino una sola página.

Gracias y saludos.

Comment: El archivo json no es html, es un método de serializado de información. Cuando veas un json en el navegador vas a ver texto plano, no interpretado. Si quieres, puedes mostrar una página web que represente ese json, y cuando hay un enlace, le pones un <a href> de ese enlace. Pero como te digo, mostrarlas una página web con forma de json, no un json puro

Comment: Cómo estás representando el JSON en la primera página? Las preguntas del tipo: "Tengo que hacer esto" sin más no suelen ser bien recibidas ya que la respuesta será siempre muy amplia y no encaja en el formato de preguntas y respuestas del sitio. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: No es muy claro lo que planteas. Además, es preciso que nos muestres lo que has intentando y qué problema tienes sobre ese código.

Comment: Efectivamente, estoy usando una página web para mostrar los datos del archivo json, Así se visualiza:
1
Descripcion: Comisión de Educación
Enlace: ir
41
Descripcion: Comisión de desarrollo Social
Enlace: ir
21
Descripcion: Comisión de deporte
Enlace: ir                                                                                                             El enlace "ir" apunta a otro archivo json, la idea es de que cuando el usuario de clic en cualquier enlace se a